# Meaning of DISP32 in objdump output

Tags: c, assembly

I'm trying to understand how string literals in C get translated into assembly.

I have a very simple C program:

```
int main() {
  char* c = "test";
}
```

Creating the object file (`gcc -c test.c`) and disassembling it via objdump (`gobjdump -SrxD test.o`) yields the following:

```
0000000000000000 <_main>:
    0:   55                      push   %rbp
    1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    4:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    6:   48 8d 0d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rcx        # d <_main+0xd>
                         9: DISP32       L_.str
    d:   48 89 4d f8             mov    %rcx,-0x8(%rbp)
   11:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   12:   c3                      retq

0000000000000013 <L_.str>:
   13:   74 65                   je     7a <L_.str+0x67>
   15:   73 74                   jae    8b <L_.str+0x78>
```

In the disassembled output it's unclear what `9: DISP32       L_.str` means. I also noticed that the corresponding machine code is missing. What exactly is this line doing?

Comment: _DISP32_ refers to the line above. The assembler is letting the linker know that it will have to compute that value at link time (when generating the final executable) . The linker will have to fill in the 32 bit displacement value that has been set to a temporary value of `0x0` (offset from Instruction pointer) with the actual displacement to L_.str . this is known as a linker fix-up.  L_.str is the label that was given to your variable `c` (character string).

Comment: If you compile your object to an executable and _objdump_ the executable you will observe the linker filled that value in with a real 32 bit displacement value.

Comment: If you are curious what the `9:` means - it says to the linker that starting at the 9th byte it needs to be filled in with a 32-Bit displacement value (notice that the 9th, 10, 11th and 12th byte are set to `00` as a temporary default value). The 32 Bit displacement value that the linker will store there when making the executable will be the displacement of `L_.str`. That is effectively what that entire informational line says.

Comment: Additionally, L_.str is the label for the string constant, which is in the code segment.  It disassembles with no meaning into the 2 jump instructions, but 74,65,73,74 is ascii for "test"